# Unix - Terminal and Shell differentiation

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, terminal

This probably sounds like a stupid question but I'm having a lot of trouble clearly differentiating between a Shell (such as Bourne) and the Terminal application like on an installation of Ubuntu or Fedora. I realise that both are completely different but I can't seem to find a clear answer written in text. Could anyone clearly distinguish between both?